# JPanel not Displaying

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, removeall

I have the code below to add JPanel to another JPanel the ui is not displayed .

I have tried changing the User_UI to just a JButton but it is not displayed as well.

It seem quite straight forward did i make a mistake ?

```
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    userArray = new User_UI[9];
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        User_UI tmp = new User_UI();            // JPanel Object
        mainPanel.add(tmp);                     // Adding to a JPanel with  GridLayout            
    }
    validate();
}
```

I have this method in my user_ui class which i used to update a JLabel. However everytime i excute the function is whole panel (mainPanel) will disapper.

```
public void setID(final String id) {

    System.out.println("ID SET to " + id);
    this.id = id;
    id_no.setText(id);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call `revalidate()` on the mainPanel after adding new components to it as this tells the containers layout managers to re-layout all components. Also the mainPanel must use a layout manager that is conducive towards allowing components to be added on the fly (i.e., not GroupLayout). Sometimes you must also call `repaint()` after revalidate, especially if components are removed.

Comment: Hi i have used validate*(. I have another issue with the ui . Can you help me as well.Thanks.

Comment: @sean: I'd love to help you more but am not sure how. If you could create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), it would do a world of good towards allowing us to better understand your problem and then help find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    userArray = new User_UI[9];
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
        User_UI tmp = new User_UI();            // JPanel Object
        mainPanel.add(tmp);                     // Adding to a JPanel with  GridLayout            
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Hi repaint works ! i have another problem with the ui can you help me take a look please thanks